# Chain NFS sharing

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

We have a storage server which for some reason cannot be reached directly (and of course not in same network). So we thought that we need to create some kind of chain NFS sharing like;

```
ServerA ----> ServerB --(?)--> ServerC
```

But whenever we want to mount a folder that has been shared from ServerA for to mount on ServerC we first mount folder to ServerB (which is fine) and then try to export the mounted folder from ServerB to mount to ServerC. But this did not work when we test it. I believe that we cannot make a chain NFS sharing or I am missing something.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Default NFS service do not support proxy so i suggest you to use ganesha which i belive solve your problem

https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki/PROXY

Comment: Sağol Emre :) deneyeceğiz.